# Changing colours crossing zero pyplot Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I want to code a Pyplot graph where it changes colors below the negative mark. I have conditions stated at the `Color Conditions` section. how would i be able to get this to work?

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [4, 5, 2, 2, 3, 5, 1, 1, 6],  
     'label':['Old','Old','Old','Old','Old','Old','Old','Old','Old'],
     'date': ['2022-01-24 10:07:02', '2022-01-27 01:55:03', '2022-01-30 19:09:03', '2022-02-02 14:34:06',
              '2022-02-08 12:37:03', '2022-02-10 03:07:02', '2022-02-10 14:02:03', '2022-02-11 00:32:25',
              '2022-02-12 21:42:03']})

CumSum_val = np.cumsum(df['col1'])
datetime = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

#Color conditions
green_cond = np.where(CumSum_val > 0)
red_cond =  np.where(CumSum_val <= 0)

# Define the date format
date_form = DateFormatter("%m-%d")
plt.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)

plt.plot(datetime[green_cond],CumSum_val[green_cond], color = 'g')
plt.plot(datetime[red_cond],CumSum_val[red_cond], color = 'r')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try plot three lines with different color, the latter has prior priority to show color.

```py
green_cond = CumSum_val > 0
red_cond =  CumSum_val <= 0

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(datetime, CumSum_val, color='b')
ax.plot(datetime[green_cond], CumSum_val[green_cond], color='g')
ax.plot(datetime[red_cond], CumSum_val[red_cond], color='r')

# Define the date format
date_form = DateFormatter("%m-%d")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The data you provided doesn't cross zero, so I took the liberty to modify this value to a given `threshold`, 15 in the below example. You can change it to whatever value you like.

The idea is to insert a new point every time the line crosses the threshold. Linear interpolation was used to achieve it. Then, to properly plot the two lines you need to select the points with:

```
green_cond = CumSum_val >= threshold
red_cond =  CumSum_val <= threshold
```

Note that I used `>=` and `<=` because I want the lines to share the common threshold point.

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, date2num, num2date

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [4, 5, 2, 2, 3, 5, 1, 1, 6],  
     'label':['Old','Old','Old','Old','Old','Old','Old','Old','Old'],
     'date': ['2022-01-24 10:07:02', '2022-01-27 01:55:03', '2022-01-30 19:09:03', '2022-02-02 14:34:06',
              '2022-02-08 12:37:03', '2022-02-10 03:07:02', '2022-02-10 14:02:03', '2022-02-11 00:32:25',
              '2022-02-12 21:42:03']})

def modify_coords(x, y, y_lim):
    """If a line segment defined by `(x1, y1) -> (x2, y2)` intercepts
    a limiting y-value, divide this segment by inserting a new point
    such that y_newpoint = y_lim.
    """
    xv, yv = [x[0]], [y[0]]
    for i in range(len(x) - 1):
        xc, xn = x[i:i+2]
        yc, yn = y[i:i+2]
        if ((yc < y_lim) and (yn > y_lim)) or ((yc > y_lim) and (yn < y_lim)):
            xv.append(((y_lim - yc) / ((yn - yc) / (xn - xc))) + xc)
            yv.append(y_lim)
        xv.append(xn)
        yv.append(yn)
    return np.array(xv), np.array(yv)

CumSum_val = np.cumsum(df['col1'])
datetime = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
datenum = date2num(datetime)

threshold = 15
datenum, CumSum_val = modify_coords(datenum, CumSum_val, threshold)
datetime = np.array(num2date(datenum))

#Color conditions
green_cond = CumSum_val >= threshold
red_cond =  CumSum_val <= threshold

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Define the date format
date_form = DateFormatter("%m-%d")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)

ax.plot(datetime[green_cond], CumSum_val[green_cond], color = 'g')
ax.plot(datetime[red_cond], CumSum_val[red_cond], color = 'r')

plt.show()
```

[image]